# combining grep and find to search for file names from query file

Tags: shell, grep, find

I've found many similar examples but cannot find an example to do the following.  I have a query file with file names (file1, file2, file3, etc.) and would like to find these files in a directory tree; these files may appear more than once in the dir tree, so I'm looking for the full path.  This option works well:

```
find path/to/files/*/*  -type f | grep -E "file1|file2|file3|fileN"
```

What I would like is to pass grep a file with filenames, e.g. with the -f option, but am not successful.  Many thanks for your insight.

This is what the query file looks like:
so the file contains one column of filenames separated by '\n' and here is how it looks like:

```
103128_seqs.fna
7010_seqs.fna
7049_seqs.fna
7059_seqs.fna
7077A_seqs.fna
7079_seqs.fna
```

Comment: Be sure that `files_to_find.txt` does not contain anything but the names of the files on each line - each line is interpreted as a *pattern*.

Comment: It contains only file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -f FILE`  gets the patterns to match from `FILE` ... **one per line***:

```
cat files_to_find.txt
n100079_seqs.fna
103128_seqs.fna
7010_seqs.fna
7049_seqs.fna
7059_seqs.fna
7077A_seqs.fna
7079_seqs.fna
```

Remove any whitespace (or do it manually):

```
perl -i -nle 'tr/ //d; print if length' files_to_find.txt
```

Create some files to test:

```
touch `cat files_to_find.txt`
```

Use it:

```
find ~/* -type f | grep -f files_to_find.txt
```

output:

```
/home/user/tmp/7010_seqs.fna
/home/user/tmp/103128_seqs.fna
/home/user/tmp/7049_seqs.fna
/home/user/tmp/7059_seqs.fna
/home/user/tmp/7077A_seqs.fna
/home/user/tmp/7079_seqs.fna
/home/user/tmp/n100079_seqs.fna
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: When I try that, I get a list of all the files that find finds.

Comment: I have cleaned up the file and this command pipe gives me the entire list that find finds.

Comment: works, needed to remove hidden carriage return with `perl -pi -E 's/\r/\n/g' `.  Thanks, cannot give you points though.